# Threads are still running in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I have 2 forms: `signin` and `control_panel`. After signin done I'm hiding this form by `this.Hide()` function and same time I am making new object of `control_panel` form and showing it by `newobj.Show();`. But when I am closing directly `control_panel` form, I am seeing first form thread are still running. I am closing it by stop_debugging button. How will I close every threads or whole program exit simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The thread for your first form is still running because you're only calling [`this.Hide`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx).** All that does is *hide* the form; it doesn't close it. Instead, you need to use [`this.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx), which will close your original form.

If you want to make sure that your entire application exits, and in the process close any forms that may still be open, you can use the [`Application.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx) method anywhere in your form's code.

**EDIT:** To expand on my last comment, you might want something like this in your `Program.cs` file:

```
static class Program
{
   /// <summary>
   /// The main entry point for the application.
   /// </summary>
   [STAThread]
   static void Main()
   {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

      SignInForm frmSignIn = new SignInForm();
      if (frmSignIn.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
      {
         //If the sign-in completed successfully, show the main form
         //(otherwise, the application will quit because the sign-in failed)
         Application.Run(new ControlPanelForm());
      }        
   }
}
```

Comment: When i am closing form by thhis.close () method my second form is being appear.I am not understanding why ?

Comment: I assume you mean that when you close the first form, your application quits? This is because in the `Program.cs` file, you have `Application.Run` set to your first form. Whenever the first form closes, the message loop ends and the application exits. I would strongly suggest placing your startup logic (i.e., showing and processing the log-in form) in the `Program.cs` file, rather than setting the log-in form to be your startup form since you plan on closing it without the application exiting.

Comment: yes u guess right.I am running Apllication.Run('..') in program.cs.And after click on signin button i am just hiding previous form making new obkject and showing the next form.How will i close whole application exit if user will click on RED CROSS button to close the program.

Comment: Using the code added to my answer in the `Program.cs` file, you can start your app showing the sign-in form. If the sign-in form returns "Yes", the sign-in was successful, and your program will show its main form (the control-panel). Otherwise, the sign-in was not successful or was canceled/closed by the user, so your program will exit. Then, later in your program, if the user wants to close, all he/she will have to do is click the red X button and it will exit automatically because your main form is now the control-panel form (instead of the sign-in form, like we said that it was earlier).

Comment: This is done now.I have a function in control_panel and in distructor i called it by this.function_name() and there i write Application.Exit; No everything is working fine.thanks Is it also good way ?

Comment: There's no reason to call `Application.Exit` in the destructor method of the form because that will be done automatically whenever that form is closed. By using `Application.Run` and specifying your main form, whenever your main form is closed, your application will *also* be closed automatically. (Assuming you mean the *actual* destructor and not a method that is called when you want to close the form programmatically.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a FormClosed event in control_panel form property window of control_panel and write the following line as

```
private void control_panel_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: Can u explain be how will i add event through properties windows which will call automatically when i will close forms.I am very new .net not fully interact with its controls.I am using C#.net2005. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is done now.I have a function in control_panel and in distructor i called it by this.function_name() and there i write Application.Exit; No everything is working fine.thanks.

Comment: then on property . there are 4 button on property button click on Event button and the search the FormClosed event.